# I would to update my model by json response, however it seems like doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am new to ember.
I want to update one of topics with json response.
`model.topics` is an array.

```js
  @action
  update(topic) {
    if (!topic || !topic.id) {
      return;
    }
    return bootbox.confirm(
      I18n.t("update.confirm"),
      I18n.t("no_value"),
      I18n.t("yes_value"),
      (result) => { 
        if (result) {
          return Topic.update(topic)
            .then((t) => {
              // t is an processed topic object from response,
              // I want to update topic with this.
              let index = this.model.topics.indexOf(
                this.model.topics.find(
                  (searchTopic) => searchTopic.id === topic.id
                )
              );
              let tmp = this.get("model.topics");
              tmp.replace(index,1,[t]);
              console.log(this.get("model.topics"));
            })
            .catch(() => {
              bootbox.alert(I18n.t("generic_error"));
            });
        }
      }
    );
  },
```

`console.log` works well.
However, when I check from ember inspector, the `model.topics` seems doesn't get updated.
Seek for some help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what happens if you close and re-open the ember inspector?

Comment: same as before.

Comment: I'm worried that the `model.topics` I've changed is not the same as the one shown in the ember.